# How to crystallize out reaction mixture from DMF?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, purification

Reaction was carried out in DMF, and TLC shows that the reaction has completed. But how to separate reaction mixture i.e. product from DMF?

**Edit**
Steglich Esterification was carried out and the product is soluble in DMF. –  user 24 (Jul 22 at 7:13)

Comment: More details would be helpful. In the standard approach, (assuming your product is something you can't precipitate or extract by acid/base workup) you'll need to select the right organic extraction solvent (less polar than DMF but sufficiently polar to dissolve your desired product, possibly $\ce{Et2O}$, $\ce{EtOAc}$, DCM, MTBE, etc.). Add it to your reaction mixture, then wash multiple times with copious water. Ideally, much of the DMF should end up in the aqueous phase. If your product is water-soluble, the situation is more difficult.